# Relay sending too many signals.

Tags: relay, 555

I have a 555 timer clk output going to the coil of a relay.  5volts going throw the contact.  The 5volts is then going to the clock bit of a CD4026 then to a 7 segment display, Seems the relay is chattering as the numbers skip (1,5,9,14,15,18) ect.. , how can i fix this.

i know its something with relay, cause if i put clk stright to CD4026 it counts perfect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmq3tN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Could I ask why you have relay in the circuit as the output from the 555 could run the counter directly and save you the problem of contact bounce.

Comment: the project is to be able to test relays,  so i have one that bypasses the relay and that goes threw relay. after 99 cycles , i make sure both counters are at 99.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are experiencing several problems:

1. No pull-down on the CLK IN input.
2. Relay contact bounce.
3. No snubber diode on the relay coil.

CMOS logic has a very high input impedance and acts like a capacitor of small value. If your relay contact closes the input charges up to 5 V and stays there when the contact opens again. What happens next depends on leakage currents at the pin and whether the pin is in an electrically noisy environment. The pin may stay HIGH or may discharge to LOW or may flicker between the two.

D1 protects the 555 and power supply against voltage spikes when the relay is switched off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAR3bn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The modified circuit.*

You need to add a pull-down resistor (because your relay is pulling up) and a capacitor to debounce. R1 and C1 in Figure 1 provide that function. Exact values are not important for your application.

Comment: And 3) no diode over the relay coil

Comment: Added, dank je.

Comment: Yeah, that schematic needs some work...

Comment: Oops! I dragged the relay to the right to make room for the diode and CircuitLab tangled the GND and wire. Fixed.

Comment: @Transistor It messed up the clk line too.

Comment: i believe that will work,  i did not have a 100nf on me, only a 330uf.  with that it works till it speed up fast and then the relay stops.

Comment: (1) No. It will take too long to discharge. The time constant is approximately R x C. (2) You should also have a 100 nF on the 555 power connections and remove R1.